# Automatically loading Word Task Pane Office Add-in

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, add-in, office365, office-js

We are developing a Word Task Pane Office Add-in (not VSTO) for internal organization documents

In Word 2013 (desktop) when we insert the add-in and save the document, when we reopen that document the add-in is automatically loaded.

In Word Online, this behavior is different, the add-in doesn't get automatically loaded. The user has to manually insert the add-in every time the document is opened.

1. Is there a way to automatically load it in Word Online?
2. Would running our own Office Web App Server help?
3. Is there a way to load the add-in through a parameter? (maybe query string?)

Thanks

Comment: I recommend you add the tag office-js as that's the one the product team monitor...

Comment: Thanks, I've added the 'office-js' tag as you suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have changed the behaviour you describe: starting in January, Word Online add-ins will be persisted in the document just like they are in Word for desktop. So #1 is not supported now but will be soon. Workarounds like #2 and #3 are not available now.

Thanks!
-Michael (Microsoft Program Manager for add-ins)

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a roadmap or feature list for what will be implemented in January? (or future releases)

Comment: In Word Online, this behavior is different, the add-in doesn't get automatically loaded. We have to manually insert the add-in every time the document is opened. It seems to be limitation with word online.

Can we get to know when automatically load task-pane support available in Word Online? Please share roadmap or feature list related link?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for posting this issue and giving us the opportunity to find a resolution. It looks like we are having a temporary issue at present where the Office Add-ins width is getting saved to 3 pixels. We are striving to find a resolution as soon as possible. In the mean time you can try the following workaround

Temporary workarounds:
1.Opening the file in excel client app and saving the file will fix the width issue because we have a minimum width set in excel client app.
2.open the file in open xml editor, locate \xl\webextensions\taskpanes.xml and edit 'width' property of entry to a greater value, say, 300.

After the file is edited in client or excel client, excel client respects the new value and it do NOT go back to value 3. The issue seems to be only repro with the add-ins inserted in excel WAC only.

We will update the article once it is fixed

Thanks,
Sky

Microsoft Program Manager.

Comment: Here is the behavior for Word: 
1. Open the document in Word Online (opens in read only mode - no add-in)  
2. On the toolbar click "Edit Document" -> "Edit in Word"   
3. Word desktop opens with the add-in loaded  
4. Close Word desktop  
5. Switch back to the browser click "Edit in Word Online" on the popup  
6. The document opens in Word Online with the add-in loaded  
Great!   
Now close the document and re-open it in Word Online (skipping the Word Desktop step) and the Add-In does NOT load. (I don’t see the 3 pixels width like Excel)